# how relove error CHECK_CXX_FLAGS failed on cmake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

when i want to compile cmake encounter bellow error

```
Using gfortran
-- Performing Test CHECK_C_FLAGS
-- Performing Test CHECK_C_FLAGS - Success
-- Performing Test CHECK_CXX_FLAGS
-- Performing Test CHECK_CXX_FLAGS - Failed
-- System is: Linux
-- Performing Test rdynamic
-- Performing Test rdynamic - Failed
```

how should I solve this?
below are my cmake command

```
cmake    -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17     -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debuge    -D  USE_EXT_DOXYGEN=0   -D USE_CUDA=0      -D OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS="-fopenmp"  -D OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES="omp"     -D CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG="std=gnu++0x"  -D CHECK_CXX_FLAG="std=gnu++11"    -D OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY="/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib"
```

Comment: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debuge`? Do you mean `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`?

Comment: Also `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG="std=gnu++0x"`? Shouldn't it be `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG="-std=gnu++0x"`? Same issue with `CHECK_CXX_FLAG`.

Comment: We could only guess what the message "Performing Test CHECK_CXX_FLAGS" means, why its status "Failed" is bad for you, what meaning of the variable `CHECK_CXX_FLAG` which you have passed to `cmake` and so on. Please, provide more details.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
I want to build and install software on ubuntu 18 LTS.

Comment: The meaning of the message and the variable I noted in my previous comment is **specific** to the project you are building. Without knowing that project we cannot help you.